# BPSim issue (Tag 'bpmn:relationship' is not imported.)

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm testing now the BPSim and after the installation, when I wanted to validate the settings i'm getting this warning:

BPMN Warning : Tag 'bpmn:relationship' is not imported. Either this file is not conforming to BPMN 2.0 Specification or EA currently does not support it.

The model i'm testing it on is a very simple BPMN (start, activity, stop)

What I need to to to resolve this warning?
As when I started to add resources I'm getting errors on resources reference

BPMN Error : ResourceRole '1st line': sub-element 'resourceRef' is not referencing to a Resource.(value 'EAID_2A118149_3458_4552_8E1E_74B7937FC3F1')

which I could not resolve either (all tagged values seems to point to proper objects) and i think it may be related to the warning.

Any clues?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to have the latest Sparx build (1227). With that build all is working.